# getElementById returning undefined

Tags: getelementbyid

I created the HTML file below to resolve why getElementById is not working.  I must be doing something wrong, but what?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
    .is-hidden { display: none; }
</style>
<body>
<h1>test this</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a onclick="enableSearch()" >Enable Search</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="search" class="is-hidden">
    <p>This is the Search area</p>
</div>
<div id="keydates">
    <p>This is the Data area</p>
</div>

<script>
function enableSearch() {
    console.log("Enable Search clicked");
    var searchArea = document.getElementById("search");
    searchArea.classlist.remove("is-hidden");
}   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on Enable Search I expect to see the line "Search Area" to appear.  This does not happen because in the Javascript console log I see "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'searchArea.classlist.remove')"

"console.log" is there simply to confirm that onclick is working.

I must add that this is a local file being accessed in Safari.  I have many Javascript functions that manipulate the HTML DOM in a local file in Safari without issue, but this is the firs time I have used getElementById.  Ticking the "Disable local file restrictions" in Safari's Develop menu makes no difference.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Typo.  The property is called `classList`.  JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be because you have classlist instead of classList. DOM properties are case sensitive.